# How do I interpret boolean transition conditions on a state diagram to a state table

Tags: boolean-logic

I am having trouble to interpret these boolean transitions on the state diagram (in the below image) to a state table. How do I for example use `b` which is 0 in a state table with two digit inputs for example a`b` which is `00`.

[image: Here is an image of the state diagram]

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your state diagram into a [state transition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table) as follows:

[image]

The `current state` together with the two inputs determines the `next state`.

**Examples:**
If the machine is in current/old state `00` and `a=1`, the next/new state is `10` regardless of `b`. If the current state is `11`, inputs `a=0, b=1` will cause a transition to state `10`.

Note that more complex machines exist which have output signals which either depend [solely on the state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine) or on a [combination of state and inputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine).